# Problem with module add

Tags: python, compiling, gcc

1. Hi, I have to do some work on **Ubuntu-20.04.3**, the pdf guide tells me to use **"module add miniconda/3"** and **"module add gcc/10.2.0"** to set up the enviroment. Then I have to use **cythonize** then compile with **gcc** and then **python** command to execute the program.
2. I used the computers at school for that so I didnt have a problem using that commands but now im trying on my pc with ubuntu.
   Everytime I use the **"module add"** command it pop ups **"module: command not found"**.
   The versions of the software seems good so I dont know why i can't use module add
   these are the versions of the software.

- python -V ---> Python 3.9.5
- cython -V ---> Cython version 0.29.24
- gcc --version ---> gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
  Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

What I need to update or install to make the things work?

UPDATE:

- I reinstalled hoping to things work but still doesnt, somehow I got Python 3.9.5
- Result of echo $PATH in Home Directory no cd command ---> /home/carlosg/miniconda3/bin:/home/carlosg/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: What is the result of `echo $PATH` please?

Answer (score 1):

The module system is part of the environment-modules package in ubuntu.  (install with `apt install environment-modules`) However, installing it is only half of the battle.

The module system is frequently used on clusters and other shared systems when  multiple conflicting software packages and versions can be installed separately in parallel subdirectories.  The environment modules package does not include that software, it is just a convenient way to manage the environment variables to integrate selected packages into your user environment.

You can install modules on your local system, but you will also have to install the individual packages you need and create modules for them.

Alternately, if you don't use conflicting software packages (like multiple versions of gcc or multiple versions of python / anaconda), you can just install the one you want and leave it in your environment permanently instead of using modules.

Some packages are available in ubuntu using the ubuntu apt system.  For example, Ubuntu 20.04 comes with python 3.8.10 and gcc 9.3, and gcc 10.3 is also available in Ubuntu via apt install.  Other packages like miniconda / anaconda can be downloaded from corresponding websites.